# Jquery droppable function parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is there any way I can pass more than one variable at a time into the Jquery.droppable function instead of just having the same function deceleration twice but with different names?

Or would this not work correctly?

**So something like**

```
var $Monday = $( "#Monday" );
var $Tuesday = $( "#Tuesday" );


$Monday.droppable, $Tuesday.droppable({      
    accept: "#gallery > li",      
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",    
    drop: function( event, ui ) {   
      }
```

instead of

```
$Monday.droppable({      
    accept: "#gallery > li",      
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",    
    drop: function( event, ui ) {   
      }

$Tuesday.droppable({      
    accept: "#gallery > li",      
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",    
    drop: function( event, ui ) {   
      }
```

Comment: have you tried $("#Monday, #Tuesday").droppable(...) and then checking the event information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at .add()

```
$Monday.add($Tuesday).doStuff(...)
```